# Safe way to pass dynamic WHERE clause to a function in Java/JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, struts

I've a method '`getAllIDs()`' which is used for getting the ids for specific table in database. It is used by many methods in my project.

```
public static int[] getAllIDs (String TableName, String WhereClause, String trxName)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT ");
        sql.append(TableName).append("_ID FROM ").append(TableName);
        if (WhereClause != null && WhereClause.length() > 0)
            sql.append(" WHERE ").append(WhereClause);
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(sql.toString(), trxName);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
                list.add(new Integer(rs.getInt(1)));
        }
}
```

Whereclause is the conditional part of query. There is a chance for sql injection due to this whereclause.
So I need to modify this method to set the parameter using prepared statement parameter setting. Problem I faced because '`getAllIDs()`' don't know how many parameters for each whereclause.

Parameters will be different for each whereclause, it can be any number. For some class, parameters will be 3 and for some it will be 2, etc having different data types. So how can i use setstring(), setint() etc. Explain me with the code which I posted.

Comment: A persistence tooling will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Pass an additional `PreparedStatementBinder` argument to the method:

```
public interface PreparedStatementBinder {
    /**
     * Binds all the arguments to the given prepared statement
     */
    public void bindArguments(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException;
}
```

The caller will have to pass a where clause (such as `"foo = ? and bar = ?"`), and an instance of this interface, such as

```
new PreparedStatementBinder() {
    @Override
    public void bindArguments(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
        statement.setString(1, theFoo);
        statement.setInt(2, theBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, it's very elegant and relatively simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible ways to do this. A simple one could be to make the `WhereClause` behave like a map where you keep parameter names and values. Then you define the prepared statement template based on the keys and fill it with values. You may need a smarter data structure if you want to join the where clauses with AND/OR keywords or use different operators for each clause: = / < / > / NOT / IS NULL etc, all this dynamically.

If you can make use of more sophisticated libraries, the Criteria API in Hibernate or other ORM tools can be really suitable for this kind of usecase.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be building an object-relational mapper (ORM), query generator, or similar.

If so, consider using an existing solution to the problem, as these are way harder to get right than they look.

Consider the JPA or Hibernate Criteria APIs; they're ugly, but comprehensive. There are many other programmatic query generators out there, not all of which are tied to ORMs.

Don't reinvent this wheel. It might look easy now, but you'll keep on hitting limitations until your design starts getting really complicated and unweildy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i got you all wrong but I am proposing a solution based on what i deduced from you statements.
Make the `Where-Clause` parameter optional like

```
public static int[] getAllIDs (String tableName, String... whereClause, String trxName)
```

and if they appears set them like

```
 for(String param:whereClause)
  {
       pst.setParameter("Param-name",param);
  }
```

Comment: The variadic parameter would need to go last. Also, this design makes it impossible to express `IS NOT NULL`. The query could use `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=` for simple equality, but even then there's no way to differentiate between "this filter criterion is not required" and "this filter criterion is a test for NULL". They've got a half-baked criteria query implementation and it's not going to be amenable to simple fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Most are suggesting a complete ORM solution like Hibernate or JPA. It will take some effort to integrate either of these if you need it for just this one query, but I'm going to guess that this is not the only query subject to SQL injection and the setup can be reused for some/most/all the queries in the app.

However, a quick-and-dirty solution is to create methods for each variation of the criteria if there are only a few of them. Each method would accept the exact type of parameter(s) required and know how to bind these arguments into a preparedStatement. There could be a factory method in the class (called by these methods) that would be passed table name, txn name, etc. and would return the SELECT and FROM clauses.

Regardless of the solution you choose, the callers of getAllIds() will need to change.